# Pandas column values to columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen a few variations on the theme of exploding a column/series into multiple columns of a Pandas dataframe, but I've been trying to do something and not really succeeding with the existing approaches.

Given a DataFrame like so:

```
    key       val
id
2   foo   oranges
2   bar   bananas
2   baz    apples
3   foo    grapes
3   bar     kiwis
```

I want to convert the items in the `key` series into columns, with the `val` values serving as the values, like so:

```
        foo        bar        baz
id
2   oranges    bananas     apples
3    grapes      kiwis        NaN
```

I feel like this is something that should be relatively straightforward, but I've been bashing my head against this for a few hours now with increasing levels of convolution, and no success.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

There are a few ways:

using [`.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
>>> df.pivot_table(values='val', index=df.index, columns='key', aggfunc='first')
key      bar     baz      foo
id                           
2    bananas  apples  oranges
3      kiwis     NaN   grapes
```

using [`.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
>>> df.pivot(index=df.index, columns='key')['val']
key      bar     baz      foo
id                           
2    bananas  apples  oranges
3      kiwis     NaN   grapes
```

using [`.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) followed by [`.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby(['id', 'key'])['val'].aggregate('first').unstack()
key      bar     baz      foo
id                           
2    bananas  apples  oranges
3      kiwis     NaN   grapes
```

Comment: @behzad.nouri could you please also extend this where there is an additional column you want to keep around? like lets say there was an additional column C in the original?

Comment: @Tommy add the columns you want to keep to the index. For example, df.pivot_table(values='val', index=['colA','colB'], columns='key', aggfunc='first')

Answer (score 10):

You could use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [1923]: df.set_index([df.index, 'key'])['val'].unstack()
Out[1923]:
key      bar     baz      foo
id
2    bananas  apples  oranges
3      kiwis    None   grapes
```

Or, a simplified `groupby`

```
In [1926]: df.groupby([df.index, 'key'])['val'].first().unstack()
Out[1926]:
key      bar     baz      foo
id
2    bananas  apples  oranges
3      kiwis    None   grapes
```