# Pandas : reshaping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is currently looks like this,

[dataframe 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZfFe.png)

I need to create a dataframe that looks like this.

[dataframe 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcUiN.png)

I need to populate the columns of dataframe 2 from the values from dataframe 1 columns. Image shows the example. 
What should be the algorithm and process for this?

Here is the sample dataset

```html
df_dict = 
{'hostname': {0: 'Comp890263', 1: 'Comp813682', 2: 'Comp213302', 3: 'Comp839013', 4: 'Comp966241'},
 
'days': {0: 90, 1: 90, 2: 90, 3: 90, 4: 90}, 

'status': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '1', 4: '1'},
 
'features': 

{0: '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0',

 1: '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', 

 2: '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', 

 3: '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,46,0,0,0,0,759,0,0,0,0', 

 4: '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,43,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,43,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,46,0,0,0,0,795,0,0,0,0'}}
```

Comment: Please include sample code to create your test DataFrames. We can't recreate dataframes from your images.

Comment: @Allen Hi. I would but the dataset  is loaded into the dataframe from postgres local database. I just used df = pd.read_sql(query,conn) to load the data.

Comment: You can do a df.head().to_dict() and paste the data here so people can reconstruct the DF to help you.

Comment: @Allen Thanks. I have added a sample dataset in dictionary for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question here :[Pandas column values to columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns). See if their solutions with `.pivot_table` or `unstack` work for you.