# Bring pandas dataframe from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bring the pandas dataframe from wide to long but I cannot find a good way to do it. Any suggestion to do this through pandas?

```
data = {'colour':["red", "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow"],
        'apple':[1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 
        'organge': [3, 4, 5, 7, 8],
        'watermelon': [7, 8, 9, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

   colour  apple  organge  watermelon
0     red      1        3           7
1    blue      2        4           8
2  yellow      4        5           9
3     red      5        7           1
4  yellow      6        8           0
```

Expected result:

```
        fruit  red  blue  yellow
0       apple    6     2      10
1     organge   10     4      13
2  watermelon    8     8       9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas column values to columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do `groupby` with `T`

```
out = df.groupby('colour').sum().T
Out[45]: 
colour      blue  red  yellow
apple          2    6      10
organge        4   10      13
watermelon     8    8       9
```

Or

```
out = df.set_index('colour').T.sum(level=0,axis=1)
Out[48]: 
colour      red  blue  yellow
apple         6     2      10
organge      10     4      13
watermelon    8     8       9
```

Comment: "Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use groupby instead." Should be `.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()` moving forward.

Comment: @BENY. `df.groupby('colour', sort=False).sum().T` to get expect outcome.