# Pandas special pivot dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Let's take a sample dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Alan","Alan","Kate","Kate","Brian"],
                   "Shop" :["A","B","C","A","B"],
                   "Amount":[4,2,1,3,5]})
    Name Shop  Amount
0   Alan    A       4
1   Alan    B       2
2   Kate    C       1
3   Kate    A       3
4  Brian    B       5
```

**First expected output :**

I would like to create a new dataframe from df having :

- as columns all the possible values in the column `Shop` and the column `Name`
- as index all the possible values in the column `Shop`, repeated for each value in column `Name'
- as values the value in the column `Àmount` matching with the columns `Name` and `Shop`

Expected output :

```
   A  B  C   Name
A  4  2  0   Alan
B  4  2  0   Alan
C  4  2  0   Alan
A  3  0  1   Kate
B  3  0  1   Kate
C  3  0  1   Kate
A  0  5  0  Brian
B  0  5  0  Brian
C  0  5  0  Brian
```

**Second expected output :**

It's almost the same as the first expected output. The only difference is that the value is the one that match with the index (and not column `Name`) and the column `Shop`.

Expected output :

```
   A  B  C   Name
A  4  4  4   Alan
B  2  2  2   Alan
C  0  0  0   Alan
A  3  3  3   Kate
B  0  0  0   Kate
C  1  1  1   Kate
A  0  0  0  Brian
B  5  5  5  Brian
C  0  0  0  Brian
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns), I tried several scripts using [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) but I didn't reach my expected outputs. Would you know please how to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with repalce missing values to `0` and for same order like original values use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
v = df['Shop'].unique()
df1 = (df.pivot('Name','Shop','Amount')
         .fillna(0)
         .astype('int')
         .reindex(df['Name'].unique()))
```

For repeat rows use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and set repeated indices by [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df = (df1.assign(Name=df1.index)
         .loc[df1.index.repeat(len(v))]
         .set_index(np.tile(v, len(df1.index)))
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
    
print (df)
   A  B  C   Name
A  4  2  0   Alan
B  4  2  0   Alan
C  4  2  0   Alan
A  3  0  1   Kate
B  3  0  1   Kate
C  3  0  1   Kate
A  0  5  0  Brian
B  0  5  0  Brian
C  0  5  0  Brian
```

For second output reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
s = df1.stack()
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy()[:, None], (len(s), len(v))),
                   columns=df1.columns, index= np.tile(df1.columns, len(df1.index)))
         .assign(Name=s.index.get_level_values(0)))

print (df2)
   A  B  C   Name
A  4  4  4   Alan
B  2  2  2   Alan
C  0  0  0   Alan
A  3  3  3   Kate
B  0  0  0   Kate
C  1  1  1   Kate
A  0  0  0  Brian
B  5  5  5  Brian
C  0  0  0  Brian
```

Alternative solution:

```
arr = np.ravel(df1)
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], (len(arr), len(v))),
                   columns=v, index= np.tile(v, len(v)))
          .assign(Name=np.repeat(df1.index, len(v)))
         )

print (df2)
   A  B  C   Name
A  4  4  4   Alan
B  2  2  2   Alan
C  0  0  0   Alan
A  3  3  3   Kate
B  0  0  0   Kate
C  1  1  1   Kate
A  0  0  0  Brian
B  5  5  5  Brian
C  0  0  0  Brian
```