# How to create a new dataframe column that contains rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given dataframe looking like this:

| ID | ID_2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 100 |
| 12 | 56 | 200 |
| 12 | 78 | 300 |

How do we:

1. Filter the dataframe with `ID_2` = 34/56/78
2. Create new columns for each of the `Value`

| ID | New column | New column_2 | New column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 100 | 200 | 300 |

Comment: There a several ways to do this. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas column values to columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [12, 12, 12], 'ID_2': [34, 56, 78], 'Value': [100, 200, 300]})

df_filtered = df[df['ID_2'].isin([34, 56, 78])]

df_pivot = df_filtered.pivot(index='ID', columns='ID_2', values='Value')
df_pivot.columns = [f"New column_{col}" for col in df_pivot.columns]

df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()

print(df_pivot)
```

which gives

```
   ID  New column_34  New column_56  New column_78
0  12            100            200            300
```